# How to remove QTabBar extra border?

Tags: qt, pyside2

I am using a `QTabBar` without a `QTabWidget` and I want to customize the tabs. However there is an extra border/edge that I can not get rid of.

[image]

Here is the code I am using.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTabBar, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PySide2.QtCore import QSize
import sys


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create a tab bar
        self.tab_bar = QTabBar()
        self.tab_bar.setStyleSheet(
            "QTabBar::tab {"
            "border: 0px solid black;"
            #    "background:red;"
            # "background:blue;"
            "}"
        )
        self.resize(QSize(300, 40))

        for i in range(5):
            self.tab_bar.addTab(f"Tab {i}")

        # Create a layout for the example widget
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tab_bar)

        # Set the layout for the example widget
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: I added `layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` after `layout.setWidget()` and it did not work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).